# Jquery / Javascript unhide div but hide button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have about 10 DIV's that I want to unhide when a button is clicked. I know how to do that.. But I want to use the same button for each DIV? Or have the button disappear when clicked so it shows the DIV but hides the button that was used to clicked it? Is something like that even possible?

Here is the code I'm trying to use..

```
<form action="{{ url_for('mod_inst.addsrvtype') }}" method="post" class="sky-form">
            <header>Add Package Template</header>
            <fieldset>


                <section>
                    <label class="label">Template Name</label>
                    <label class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter a name.. 3 Package Private Lesson, etc">
                    </label>
                    <div class="note"><strong>Note:</strong> This is required, your students will not see this name.</div>
                </section>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <label class="label">Price</label>
                        <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-dollar"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="price" value="">
                        </label>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <label class="label">Tax</label>
                        <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-percent"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="tax" value="">
                        </label>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                 <button type="button" class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
                 <div class="hidden">
                 Hello
                 <div class="row">
                 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
                 <div class="hidden">
                 Hello
                 <div class="row">
                 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
                 <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
                </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
                 </div>

            </fieldset>
            <footer>
                <button type="submit" class="button">Add Service</button>
                <button type="button" class="button button-secondary" onClick="window.history.back();">Cancel</button>
            </footer>

            <!-- END CONTENT -->

        </div><!-- END accordion CONTENT -->
</div><!-- END accordion ITEM -->
```

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".hideDiv");

// Set up event handlers for each
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i){
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
    this.classList.add("hidden");
  });
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a button with an id "button", for example, and use jquery to show the div's and hide the button.
`$("#button").click(function(){
     $("div").show();
     $("#button").hide();
 });`

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I am looking for.. so "#button" would be the id for the button right? and "div" would be the id for the div?

Comment: yes #button is the id for the button but "div" is just the html tag div, not an id.

Comment: This solution requires that each button have a separate event handler that  hard codes the id's of the elements to hide and show.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
// Get all the buttons
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".hideDiv");

// Set up event handlers for each
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i){
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
    this.classList.add("hidden");
  });
}
```

```css
div.hidden, button { float:left; }
.hidden { display:none; }
.row { clear:both; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
 <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
 <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
 <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
 <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <button class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
 <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using the following code..

'<div class="row">
      <button type="button" class="hideDiv">Unhide this row</button>
      <div class="hidden">
       Cannot See This!
      </div>
     </div>

<script type="text/javascipt">
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".hideDiv");

// Set up event handlers for each
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i){
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
    this.classList.add("hidden");
  });
}

 </script>'

But it doesn't seem to be showing the div.. any ideas?

Comment: @ChristopherNelson And?

Comment: There are no errors when inspecting the page, it just seems like the on clicking the javascript is never called.

Comment: Where and how are you including the JavaScript I've shown? It should be in a `<script>  </script>` element that comes just before the closing of the body (`</body>`).

Comment: Yeah, it is.. when inspecting the page I can see it is render (I'm using Jinja2) would it matter that I added type="button" to the button?

Comment: I see it doesn't matter since it works with the type=button in JSfiddle..

Comment: The type isn't relevant. I don't know anything about Jinja2, but as you can see, the code I've provided does work. We'd need to see your code because, clearly something in there is preventing this from working. You should edit your question to include your relevant code.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I updated the original question with the included code. I also tried running the code just on a local regular HTML page and still couldn't get it to run. Although in JS Fiddle my code seems to work fine so I'm not sure what could be going on here..